# Mac OSX Filesystem modification program. Error: "kevent register: Bad file descriptor"

Tags: c++, macos, filesystems, osx-yosemite, fsevents

I am writing a program to monitor when files are written to the Mac OSX filesystem using C++. I am calling fsevents directly so that I can get the PID of the process that wrote the file to the filesystem.

When I run the program under my username, I receive an error "kevent register: Bad file descriptor" pertaining to line 43 of my program. If I run it as sudo, the program runs without an error but never receives notifications of files written. I test this out by issuing: `echo "blah" >> /tmp/1234`.

The code:

```
#include "fcntl.h"      //for O_RDONLY
#include "errno.h"      //for errno
#include "stdio.h"    //for fprintf()
#include "string.h"     //for strerror()
#include "stdlib.h"     //for EXIT_SUCCESS
#include "sys/event.h"  //for kqueue() & more
#include "unistd.h"     //for close()
#include <err.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>  //for iotcl control working with fsevents

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Exectuted");

    struct kevent kev_set;  /* Event we want to monitor */
    struct kevent kev_retr; /* Event triggered */
    int kq, fd, ret;

    // directory to monitor, NO checks for errors here
    fd = open ("/dev/fsevents", O_RDONLY);

    //if (ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &status) >= 0)
    //    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "TIOCMGET failed:");

    kq = kqueue();
    if (kq  == -1)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "kqueue() failed");

    /* Initialize kevent structure. */
        EV_SET(&kev_set, fd, EVFILT_VNODE, EV_ADD | EV_CLEAR, NOTE_WRITE, 0, NULL);

        /* Attach event to the  kqueue. */
        ret = kevent(kq, &kev_set, 1, NULL, 0, NULL);
        if (ret == -1)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "kevent register");

    for (;;) {
        /* Sleep until something happens */
        printf("Starting loop\n");
        ret = kevent(kq, NULL, 0, &kev_retr, 1, NULL);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "kevent wait");
        }
        else if (ret > 0) {
                 printf("Something was written: ");
                }
    }

    close(fd);

}
```

The output:

```
$ ./fsmon-test 
fsmon-test: kevent register: Bad file descriptor
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure whether your problem has something to do with Qt at all. Am I correct that the `for(;;)` loop prevents `a.exec();` to be reached. If `a.exec()` is not entered Qt cannot "get alive" as updating of widgets and a lot of other things depends on the event queue (driven by `QApplication::exec()`). _I_ would first check whether your file system monitoring works on its own (removing all Qt code). May be, Qt and file system monitoring are interfering with each other, may be not. Something _I_ would like to clarify first...

Comment: You make a good point there. I moved the a.exec() line (removing the return) above the for(;;) loop, and the application window appeared.

I removed all Qt code and compiled it with g++. I received the same error: "fsmon-test: kevent register: Bad file descriptor".